# Clear all items from view in single page app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, single-page-application

I have a single page app (written in Backbone) backed by a database where the default (for the time being) is to list a certain number of items, however, I wish to provide the option to sort by date or some other criterion. Therefore, I need to be able to clear all items from the screen and query the db for the items that meet the criterion.

question: what is the general strategy for clearing all the views already on the screen before reloading the new items from the db?

Note, in the Backbone TodoMVC app, the strategy is to simply use css visible/hidden to toggle between different states, but this is unworkable if an application is backed by a db with a lot of items and only 30 are shown initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to delete the Events as well you will need to undelegate events, as if you didn't do so and you created a new Backbone view the old view will still listen to actions and if you have a click callback will be triggered for new and old one

```
destroy:=>
  @.undelegateEvents() 
  @$(el).empty()
```

Comment: Sorry not a coffee scripter, why the '.' After @?

Comment: @ is this then its this.undelegateEvents();

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jquery, you can clear the contents of the div using its id

```
$("#divID").empty();
```

And then append some kind of sub-element for each entry you retrieve from the db

```
$("#divID" ).append("<p>Element #1</p>");
```